# How can I update only Chocolatey packages that are verified by moderators?

Tags: powershell, chocolatey

I use Chocolatey to install/update applications on my PC. Is there any way to make sure that the packages I install have been approved by moderators?

If I simply do a `choco install <package name>` I might get a warning that the package is not trusted and to press <kbd>N</kbd> or <kbd>Y</kbd> to continue, but it's a tedious task to confirm each package. Is there a simpler way to do this? I'm looking for a parameter I can set like `-AutoDenyUntrustedPackages`?

A side note, I know you can also use ChocolateyUI, but it never prompts regarding untrusted packages. Is that due to a security flaw or will it only allow updates if the update itself has been verified by a moderator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to install a package which is not yet verified by a moderator, [you have to specify the version](https://chocolatey.org/faq#how-do-i-install-a-package-version-under-moderation). These packages will not be installed or updated automatically, meaning the actual behavior you describe is implemented by default.

Trusted packages mean something else: they are packages which come from a trusted source (like the creator of the program which the package installs). These packages skip human moderation.

Comment: More to comment - feel free to add. You may be seeing part of a transition to look at packages that have checksums when the source is over HTTP. This is a security change we needed to make. Packages up to a certain point could still be approved, even with no checksums. Only packages moving forward AFTER the requirement would be held for maintainers to fix.

Comment: A way to see what packages are approved, `choco search name` (additionally adding `--verbose` \ `-v` will produce even more information). If you want to get it down to a specific package, there is `choco info name` or you can also pass options to `choco search` (see `choco search -?` for details). https://chocolatey.org/docs/commands-list

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Now I feel a little safe using Chocolatey again.